# Find the number of connected objects in a given 2-D binary matrix?

Tags: c

**I've tried my best by applying the code to the specification provided in a problem.
This is the question,
Find the number of connected objects in a given 2-D binary matrix.**
Number of connected objects = 2
Function Definitions:
void objectCount (int **, int ,int ,int ,int )
Actually what i programmed is to find only the islands,but the question asked is to find the connected 1's not to account single 1.
my code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void objectCount(int **a,int row,int col,int i,int j)
{
    int d;
    if(i<0 || i>=row)
    d=0;
    if(j<0 || j>=col)
    d=0;
    else
    d=1;

    if(d && a[i][j]==1)
    {
        a[i][j]=0;
        objectCount(a,row,col,i-1,j-1);
        objectCount(a,row,col,i-1,j);
        objectCount(a,row,col,i-1,j+1);
        objectCount(a,row,col,i,j-1);
        objectCount(a,row,col,i,j+1);
        objectCount(a,row,col,i+1,j-1);
        objectCount(a,row,col,i+1,j);
        objectCount(a,row,col,i+1,j+1);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int r,o,count=0;
    printf("Enter number of rows:\n");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    printf("Enter number of columns:\n");
    scanf("%d",&o);
    int **a =(int**)malloc(r * sizeof(int *));
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    *(a+i)=(int*)malloc(o * sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter the matrix:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<o;j++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<o;j++)
        if(a[i][j]==1)
        {
           count++;
           objectCount(a,r,o,i,j);
        }
    }
    printf("Number of connected objects = %d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

I got the message segmentation fault,while compiling.

````
Enter number of rows:
5
Enter number of columns:
5
Enter the matrix:
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
Number of connected objects = 2```

Please try for some 8 X 5 matrix too.
Kindly please explain what should i code to get the exact output.
````

Comment: What are _connected objects_ (in the context of your 2-D binary matrix) ?

Comment: The 1's which are connected more than one,is known as one connection object. Here the 1's on the left side and the right side made two objects

Comment: one thing I found is, code I entered passes only the test case i provide, if you change the matrix the code is dumped.

Comment: something is wrong in the function object count.

Comment: something I understood is  to add else if , here instead of if 
    if(i<0 || i>=row)
    d=0;
    else if(j<0 || j>=col)
    d=0;
    else
    d=1;